# how to animate()

Tags: jquery

Dreamweaver doesn't say I have any syntax errors, so why isn't my background color changing?

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#contact").hover(function () {
        $("#contactform").stop().fadeIn(500);
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: "260px",
            background: "blue"
        });
    }, function () {
        $("#contactform").stop().fadeOut(500);
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: "20px",
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: If you want to animate colors, you should load jQuery UI or a plugin that provides support for it.

Comment: I wish I could accept your comment as an answer. That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct tag for just changing the color should be 'background-color'

```
$(this).stop().animate({
    height: "260px",
    'background-color': "blue"
});
```

Also make sure you have included jQuery UI.

Comment: Please see @undefined's comment above. jQuery does not support animating colors out of the box.

Comment: Hey Rusty where do you live in Antioch? I just moved from there to Brentwood.

Comment: How do we know the OP has not included jQuery UI?

Comment: @AlienWebguy Deer Valley and Lone Tree.

Comment: Crazy, I lived near there, on Eagle Ridge->Aspen Way, behind InShape.

Comment: Hmm, cool, I actually live off Eagleridge, just past Asilomar. Just got back from In-Shape earlier. :P

Comment: @AlienWebguy How did you get Google to censor your house? http://goo.gl/maps/0tjND

Comment: Haha I reported it as inappropriate content (bottom left of the map, little hidden *Report a Problem* link) :)